# Группировка записей в таблице по полю и скрытие под спойлером

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Друзья, искренни прошу помощи. Мучает данный вопрос уже не один месяц, сталкиваюсь с необходимостью его решения в различных проектах. Итак вот суть.

Есть таблица в БД. к примеру cards.

В таблице есть множество полей, одно из них  group

В таблице cards есть 15 записей, 10 из которых имеют значение group, к примеру 1

Что нужно:

1) Так как записи разбросаны в хаотичном порядке, в первую очередь нужно отсортировать по группе, что бы все карты, которые имеют группу 1 были по порядку в массиве одна за другой.

2) Как только мы встречаем первую из 10 карт которые имеюют одну и ту же группу (1) - выводим ее на экран, а далее, остальные 9 карт скрываем под спойлером. и так далее со всеми. Если карте присвоена какая-то группа, в которой больше нет карт - то просто выводим, если встречаем группу карт - выводим первую из них, остальные скрываем под спойлером.

Я много думал и так и не понимаю можно ли это сделать в одном цикле, либо надо думать как то по другому?

вот код:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cards ORDER BY group");
while($card = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  //далее не знаю как можно это реализовать но более наглядно покажу что хочу

  echo $card['name']."<br/>"; //вывели к примеру карту, у которой группа 0
  //Встретили карту с группой  1 (следующие 3 карты в массиве также имеют группу 1, поэтому выводим первую попавшею, а далее вставляем все остальные которые найдем с этой же группы под спойлер.

  //Вот, к примеру, код спойлера:
  <div class="spoiler-wrapper">
  <div class="spoiler folded"><a href="javascript:void(0);">Название первой карты из группы</a></div><div class="spoiler-text">Все остальные карты из группы</div></div>
}
```

Comment: расширение mysql уже устарело и удалленно в php7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну наверное не надо ломать голову , а просто вывести все как есть походу проставляя атрибуты в виде id группы и через JS все обрабатывать. Вот пример скрипта который будет прятать все однотипные записи в спойлер оставляя только верхнюю:

```js
var d = $(document) , groupBlock = "" , el = "" , count ;

//Обойти все записи которые подлежат группировке в спойлер , 
$("[data-group]").each(function(){
 el = $(this);
 groupBlock = d.find(".container-"+el.data("group"));
    count = d.find("[data-group="+el.data("group")+"]").length ;
  
  //если запись уже имеет корневую группу , добавим элемент в нее , иначе создадим контэйнер
  if(groupBlock.length){
   el.appendTo(groupBlock); 
  }else{
    //если однокоренных записей больше 1 , добовляем контэйнер
    if(count > 1){
     el.append("<div class='block container-"+el.data("group")+"'></div>").addClass("first")
    }
  }
  
  //событие при клике на корневую группу , отобразить спойлеры
}).on('click',function(){
     $(this).find("div.block").stop().slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.block{
  display:none;
  padding:3px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
.first{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-group='0'>Первый </div>
<div data-group='0'>Первый </div>
<div data-group='0'>Первый </div>
<div data-group='0'>Первый </div>
<div data-group='0'>Первый </div>

<div data-group='1'>второй </div>
<div data-group='1'>второй </div>
<div data-group='1'>второй </div>
<div data-group='1'>второй </div>

<div data-group='3'>третий</div>
<div data-group='4'>четвертый</div>
<div data-group='4'>четвертый</div>
<div data-group='5'>пятый</div>
```

Comment: Искренни благодарен!

Comment: Простите а еще такой вопрос, вот карты с конкретной группы мне группировать не нужно, к примеру это группа под номером 0. Как можно изменить скрипт?

Comment: Спасибо я уже сделал что нужно, что то я спросоня наглею)) Еще раз благодарен вам за решение!

Comment: Пожалуйста , пользуйтесь))

Comment: В том вопросе к сожалению не удалось высветлить суть того что мне осталось сделать. я уже пару часов мучаюсь так и не могу допереть. смотрите:

Comment: куда смотреть то?

Comment: //событие при клике на корневую группу , отобразить спойлеры
}).on('click',function(){
// Здесь нужно проверить или это был клик на конкретный div class="cardname" а не отрабатывать событие при клике на всю группу.
- именно в этом вопрос.
     $(this).find("div.block").stop().slideToggle();
});

Comment: Дай реальный пример кода , что бы было понятно , можеш на jsfiddle запостить

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=m96LFp4hHE

Comment: к сожалению оно не работает, но в комментариях к событию ОН я написал что нужно, наглядно возможно вы поймете что нужно

Comment: Что то там пусто =(

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dfspxtok/ :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47140/discussion-between-redroid-and-isee-dev).